# failed to drive pr2 robot on multi_level_map_demo gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [pr2_simulator/Tutorials/MultiLeveMapWithRamps](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/MultiLeveMapWithRamps).

I use ROS electric to run

```
  roslaunch pr2_gazebo_wg multi_level_map_demo.launch
  rosrun pr2_teleop teleop_pr2_keyboard
```

But I can't move pr2 on teleop_pr2_keyboard node.

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38344/failed-to-drive-pr2-robot-on-multi_level_map_demo-gazebo/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found that one solution.

```
  roslaunch pr2_teleop teleop_keyboard.launch
```

Thank you~

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0